# Django admin list display - prefetch against custom names

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created some custom names for my list display but they are generating over 500 queries in my admin list display. I have added a select and prefetch QuerySet (which works on the edit form) and looks to have cut some of the list display down.

However I think the get_xxx fields need to be prefetched too? but am not sure on how to do this?

```
class DeviceCircuitSubnetsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['device__hostname','circuit__ref_no','subnet__subnet_type__subnet_type','subnet__subnet',]
    list_display = ('get_device','get_circuit','get_subnet','get_subnet_type')

    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(DeviceCircuitSubnetsAdmin, self).queryset(request) \
                                                    .select_related('circuit') \
                                                    .select_related('device') \
                                                    .select_related('subnet') \
                                                    .prefetch_related('device__site_') \
                                                    .prefetch_related('circuit__circuit_type') \
                                                    .prefetch_related('circuit__provider') \
                                                    .prefetch_related('subnet__subnet_type') \

    def get_device(self, obj):
        return obj.device.site
    get_device.admin_order_field  = 'device'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_device.short_description = 'Device'  #Renames column head

    def get_circuit(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.circuit.ref_no
        except: 
            return ''
    get_circuit.admin_order_field  = 'circuit__ref_no'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_circuit.short_description = 'Ref No'  #Renames column head

    def get_subnet(self, obj):
        return obj.subnet.subnet
    get_subnet.admin_order_field  = 'subnet__subnet'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_subnet.short_description = 'Subnet'  #Renames column head

    def get_subnet_type(self, obj):
        return obj.subnet.subnet_type
    get_subnet_type.admin_order_field  = 'subnet__subnet_type__subnet_type'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_subnet_type.short_description = 'Subnet Type'  #Renames column head
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things Alex.

1. ModelAdmin should have `get_queryset` function defined, not `queryset`.
2. There is a typo in one of `prefetch_related` calls, code is not failing because of point 1)
3. Are all fields you list in `prefetch_related` a foreign keys? Because you should use prefetch related only in this case.

In general, don't be worried about get_xxx functions. They will work
    on objects fetched using your queryset - so if you fetch what you
    need, there will be no additional queries.